# How can I update first_name, last_name & email of Django model User and update other field in separate models

Tags: python, django

I have been learning the Django tutorial for a few weeks using YT, StackOverflow, Django documentation, and other sources. So, maybe my question goes out of the sense. I hope you will understand my question. If anything is a mistake on my code or you want to give me some suggestions, then reply to me.

I make the site locally on my computer. First of all, I have created a signup page and login page using
Django Model.

After User login the site, In profile settings, I have created form field like **first_name**, **last_name**, **email**, **mobile_number**, **date_of_birth**, **zip_code**, **address**, **website**, **bio**, **etc**.

I have **models.py** for Account setting

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile', null=True)
    mobile_number = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null= True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=225, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=225, null=True)
```

In **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Account

class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = '__all__'
```

In **templates**

```
<form class="form mx-auto my-5" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="user" type="hidden" value="{{request.user.id}}" required>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="first_name" class="font-weight-bold">First name (required):</label>
        <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" value="{% if request.user.first_name %}{{request.user.first_name}}{% endif %}" required>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="middle_name">Middle name (optional):</label>
        <input name="middle_name" type="text" id="middle_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle name">
      </div> -->
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="last_name">Last name (optional):</label>
        <input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" value="{% if request.user.last_name %}{{request.user.last_name}}{% endif %}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="font-weight-bold">Email address:</label>
      <input name="email" type="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="{{request.user.email}}" placeholder="Your email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="mobile_number" class="font-weight-bold">Mobile number:</label>
        <input name="mobile_number" type="tel" id="mobile_number" class="form-control" placeholder="98********" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="date_of_birth" class="font-weight-bold">Date of birth:</label>
        <input name="date_of_birth" type="date" id="date_of_birth" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="zip_code" class="font-weight-bold">Zip code:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" type="number" min="00000" max="99999" placeholder="55455">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input name="address" type="text" id="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Bharatpur-07, Chitwan, Nepal">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="website">Website:</label>
        <input name="website" type="url" id="website" class="form-control" placeholder="https://example.com/">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="bio">Bio:</label>
        <textarea name="bio" class="form-control" id="bio" rows="5"></textarea>   
      </div>
      <div class="col form-group">
        <br><br>
        <span>Write something about your</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md px-3 my-0 mr-0 float-right" type="submit">Submit</button
</form>
```

I tried in **views.py**, it worked.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import AccountForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.
def profileSettingsPage(request, pid):
    form = AccountForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if int(request.POST.get('user')) == request.user.id:
            if form.is_valid():
                user = User.objects.get(pk=pid)
                 user.first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
                 user.last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
                 user.email = request.POST.get('email')
                 user.save()

                 form.save()

                 messages.success(request, 'Profile saved.')
                 return redirect('profile-settings', pid)
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Sorry! You enter other username.')
            return redirect('profile-settings', pid)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'profile-settings.html', context)
```

But, I want to **validate** for first_name, last_name, email field before saving. I was expecting some **is_valid()** to save.

Also, I **tried** something new

Now, In **views.py** I added

```
from pages.forms import CreateUserForm
```

which was created for signup page

Then, **views.py** looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import AccountForm

from pages.forms import CreateUserForm

from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.
def profileSettingsPage(request, pid):
    form1 = AccountForm()
    form2 = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = AccountForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form2 = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if int(request.POST.get('user')) == request.user.id:
            if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
                form2.save()
                form1.save()

                messages.success(request, 'Profile saved.')
                return redirect('profile-settings', pid)
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'Faile to saved profile')
                return redirect('profile-settings', pid)
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Sorry! You enter other username.')
            return redirect('profile-settings', pid)
    context = {'form1':form1, 'form2':form2}
    return render(request, 'profile-settings.html', context)
```

But, This is not worked for me. **form1.is_valid()** and **form2.is_valid()** can not pass **True** value and give me message "Failed to saved profile."

My question is, I want to update the **first_name**, **last_name**, **email** field of the Django model User, and other fields are separately updated to the next model.

**Another question**

In the above **models.py**, I have use **ForeignKey()** to get the User(username or id).

In **templates**, I have used **{{ request.user.id }}** to get user.

**Is it possible to get User (id or username) without touching *views.py,* *forms.py* and *templates*?**

**Edit:**
**I got an answer on this link:**
[I am unable to update two models at the same time in Django Views.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887692/i-am-unable-to-update-two-models-at-the-same-time-in-django-views-py)

Comment: Did you check if your `{{ request.user.if }} is returning any ID or not? Because you haven't passed in the request variable in the context for the template.

Comment: Also, if you just want to update the model, you can pass in the instance of user to your user_form while creating its object. That way you won't even need to pass in the id of the user to the template.

Comment: Yes, {{request.user.id}} give me id. But in views.py, I checked request.POST.get('user') == request.user.id and it return False although value is same.Then, i found somewhere, convert id to int. Then I checked int(request.POST.get('user')) == request.user.id. Finally it worked. But my question is like in models.py is there any possible like user = request.user.id instead of ForeignKey

Comment: For the update model, @BATMAN can you give a sample code of passing instance. Because it tried a lot or I mistake somewhere, it only updated AccountForm only not django User

Comment: Did you fix your problem for update and the id you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the `user_id` in the context to the template and then use it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, But I am curious to know that, is there any way to get a user id or username in models.py by passing id from somewhere? example user = request.user.id or request.user.username so that I can replace ForeignKey.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile', null=True)
    mobile_number = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null= 
    True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=225, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=225, null=True)

def profileSettingsPage(request):
    form1 = AccountForm()
    form2 = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        instance_user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        instance_account = Account.objects.get(user=instance_user)
        form1 = AccountForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=instance_account)
        form2 = CreateUserForm(request.POST,instance=instance_user)

        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form2.save()
            form1.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile saved.')
            return redirect('profile-settings')
        else:
            print(form1.errors)
            print(form2.errors)
            messages.warning(request, 'Faile to saved profile')
            return redirect('profile-settings')
    context = {'form1':form1, 'form2':form2}
    return render(request, 'profile-settings.html', context)
```

Comment: user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

Comment: share your whatsaap contact