# I am unable to update two models at the same time in Django Views.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I already ask questions related to this at
[How can I update first_name, last_name & email of Django model User and update other field in separate models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63877671/how-can-i-update-first-name-last-name-email-of-django-model-user-and-update-o)

But I'm not getting a proper solution. That's why I make this question similar to that one.

I have **pages.views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import CreateUserForm
from accounts.models import Account
from django.contrib import messages

def signupPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()

                # focus on this line
                Account.objects.create(user=user)

                messages.success(request, 'Signup success. Now, you can login.')
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'Signup failed. Please, try again.')
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```

Also, I have **accounts.models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Account(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # This field is used for to update django model User
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile', null=True)
    mobile_number = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null= True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=225, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=225, null=True)
```

In **Accounts.view.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import AccountForm
from .models import Account
from pages.forms import CreateUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

First of all I tried this:

```
def profileSettingsPage(request, pid):
    user= User.objects.get(id=pid)
    form = AccountForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():

            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            user.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user.save()

            form.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Profile saved.')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Faile to saved profile')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'profile-settings.html', context)
```

But It will only save the User model, not AccountForm.

Then I replace `user = request.user`. Again, it save the user model only, not AccountForm.

Again, I replace `user = Account.objects.get(id=pid)`. Then, I faced error **DoesNotExist: Account matching query does not exist.**

Even I tried this

```
def profileSettingsPage(request, pid):
    form = AccountForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = User.objects.get(id=pid)
            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            user.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile saved.')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Faile to saved profile')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'profile-settings.html', context)
```

It saves both the models, but the problem was it created a new one and save the null value in the ForeignKey of Account model, other fields saved as it is, and also saved the User model with those values.

Now, **my question is how can I update the Account model that I created in pages.views.py and Django User model at the same times ?**

I get confused on passing instance value. **Did I did the same as everyone does? or Did I do some mistake ?**

Comment: user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) you can use OneToOneFiled instead of ForeignKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Account(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # This field is used for to update django model User
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile', null=True)
    mobile_number = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null= True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=225, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=225, null=True)

def profileSettingsPage(request, pid):
    form = AccountForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.objects.get(id=pid)
        user.first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        user.email = request.POST.get('email')
        user.save()
        instance = Account.objects.get(user=user)
        form = AccountForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile saved.')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Faile to saved profile')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'profile-settings.html', context)
```

Comment: Somewhere on StackOverflow, I found form.cleaned_data.get() is better than request.POST.get(). That why i used form.cleaned_data.get(). AM I RIGHT?

Comment: you are not using CreateUserForm so I have used request.POST

Comment: I have added three fields (first_name, last_name, and email) on the Account Model to use form.cleaned.data.get(), Anyway, THANKS TO YOU, it worked!. Finally, I get the proper solution after researching the whole day. Now, I can go to bed because I'm feeling asleep.